# Semicolon usage: I've got the truck; now I need some muscle

Tags: semicolons

In the sentence:

> I’ve got the truck**;** now I need some muscle.

Is the semicolon the correct punctuation to put just after *truck*, just before *now*?

Comment: Looks correct to me. You're joining two independent, closely related clauses. Here's a fun post on semicolon use: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon

Answer (score 2):

The semi-colon is a fun punctuation mark. It adds variety to sentence structure, whether in writing or speaking. Your use of it in your exemplar is not only correct, but I like the sound of it. Or, put differently,

> Your use of the semi-colon in your exemplar is not only correct; I also like the sound it creates.

Joining two independent clauses with a conjunction (e.g., and, but, as, and because) can become a habit which needs to be broken occasionally. The abruptness, as it were, created by the semi-colon may at times make our utterance or writing more memorable.

In other words, two independent clauses balanced by the inclusion of a conjunction are fine when used in moderation. At other times, however, two independent clauses, less the conjunction, provide balance on their own.